# Wrong inductance at flyback transformer?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, flyback, linear

I want to design a 12V-to-48V@0,3A isolated DC-DC converter using [LT8302](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/8302fc.pdf) and I was following the design example given in the datasheet.

Using the values for "8V to 36VIN/48VOUT Isolated Flyback Converter" at p. 22:

Vin_min = 8V, Vin_nom = 12V, Vin_max = 32V, Vout = 48V, I_out = 0,2A

it results that the primary inductance needs to be greater than 58uH, but as you can see at p. 22, they chose a transformer with primary inductance of 9uH. **Why? Is it a design mistake?**

I have uploaded (at the links below) an Excel file with the design example where you can enter the input values and see the results. In red are the values for the converter I want to design.

[OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqS89PPxByssgSmVJaFyOoH3LYss)

[File](https://ufile.io/4fdef)

Comment: I am surely not going to open an excel file from dubious sources.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I would have uploaded it here, but I did not find an option to add attachments. The file is OK.

Comment: Where do you get 58uH? The calculation on P.18 yields >= 5.9 uH.

Comment: @CristianM: the source would still be the same

Comment: 5.9uH plays 58uH, sounds like a factor of 10 error

Comment: You need to show what formula you are using and the various voltage and load values you have entered so that somebody can check your math. Nobody is going to open the spreadsheet except a fool and, no doubt it is virus free but, do you want a fool's answer?

Comment: @BrianDrummond The calculation on p. 18 is for a converter with 5V@1,5A output. I used the formulas for 48V/0,2A output, as it is indicated in their reference design at p. 22, intending to understand how to design a converter with 48V/0,3A which I need.

Comment: @Andyaka The formulas are given in the converter datasheet, at p. 18 (see steps 1 and 2). I've updated my question.

Comment: ah... but VOut seen at the primary and VOut seen at the secondary are related by the turns ratio ... and the inductances are related by turns squared. Were you using Nps=4 (as in the p22 example) when you got 58uH?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I was using Nps=1:4=0.25, as in the p. 22 example.

Comment: In your spreadsheet, cell B11 yields 58uH, what Nps are you using? It looks like 3, shouldn't it be more like 0.3. That is the factor of 10 difference as indicated by Brian Drummond.

Comment: I see where Nps=3 comes from now, It is from page 18. But what is on that page is not your actual design.

Comment: @rioraxe I'm using Nps = 0.25. Yes, Nps = 3 is from the design of the 12V-to-5V@1.5A converter, at p. 18.